# Girl goes over to the other site of her house and encounters her button-eyed "other parents"

Tags: story-identification

I read a book, whose title I've forgotten, in the fifth grade, which was about a girl who somehow *'went over' to the wrong side of her house* and found that her parents (and brother, maybe?) had **'black button-like'** eyes in the 'other house'. Her **button-eyed parents** and **real parents** coexist, but her real parents do not know of the existence of the button-eyed​ parents.

She somehow finds a way to speak to the **button-eyed parents** frequently(I think she was compelled to do so) by crossing over from her real house to the **'other house'**, but doesn't like them. They have an evil aura.

I'm afraid that's all I remember, and I know it's *vague and sketchy*, but that's the most I remember now!

Comment: You can see the edit history [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/165897/revisions) and by clicking the "edited x mins/hours ago" link above.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: @Yakk , I preferred using Stack Exchange due to the fact that experts answer my questions. I felt that I was likely to run into quite a good deal of irrelevant stuff if I surfed the Net for an answer, and chose to ask my question on a site where I could expect reliable and accurate answers. Still, I'll bear in mind to research any future questions before bringing them to the site!

Comment: @HarryWeasley I understand.  I am simply quoting what the downvote button says; and honestly, did you do any research at all prior to asking this question?

Comment: @Yakk , fair enough! As a newcomer, I've done a lot to learn, and your advice is part of that! :) Thank you! And, to be honest, Stack Exchange was the first site I went looking for answers!

Comment: @Yakk , I meant I *have got a lot to learn*, not *done a lot to learn*! Autocorrect!

Comment: Weird, I don't seem to be able to edit my comments.

Comment: @HarryWeasley Comments can only be edited in the first 5 minutes after posting.

Comment: Well, my search for “button-eyed parents” did require some digging to get to Coraline.  That is part of the fun, though:  whatever the rules of SE, don't always be to wary to wander the internet.  You never know what you might discover.  Of course, not every discovery is a pleasant one … Whatever; Valorum likes the rep.

Comment: @8bittree Thanks, I didn't know that!

Comment: @Yakk To be honest though, give it a while and this will be the new top answer when someone searches "Button eyed parents", then nobody will ever have to ask again. As can-ned_food said, at the moment it does take a bit of digging. (That and there's a conspiracy to get valorum up to 300k before Christmas.)

Comment: Hey, I saw a notification saying that I got some (-4) reputation points for this question. Does anyone know why? I'm not used to Stack Exchange and its system!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This is [Coraline](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17061.Coraline) by Neil Gaiman.

> Coraline's often wondered what's behind the locked door in the drawing room. It reveals only a brick wall when she finally opens it, but when she tries again later, a passageway mysteriously appears. Coraline is surprised to find a flat decorated exactly like her own, but strangely different. And when **she finds her "other" parents in this alternate world,** they are much more interesting despite their **creepy black button eyes**. When they make it clear, however, that they want to make her theirs forever, Coraline begins a nightmarish game to rescue her real parents and three children imprisoned in a mirror. With only a bored-through stone and an aloof cat to help, Coraline confronts this harrowing task of escaping these monstrous creatures.

It may interest you to learn that they made it into an animated feature film.

Comment: Wow, @Valorum , that was really quick! I checked the link you sent, it is the right book! Thanks for the answer, it's spot-on and helps me a lot! (+1)

Comment: How, @Valorum , did you identify it so quickly? Feels über-fast!

Comment: "Black button eyes" was the phrase that stayed in my mind, even after so long!

Comment: @HarryWeasley, you have no idea how good Valorum is at this.  Your question was a tad easy (it was made into a very popular stop motion film) but Valorum and Fuzzyboots are able to find the most obscure stuff in a matter of seconds.  This stackexchange is inhabited by robots, I am almost certain.

Comment: @HarryWeasley - Buttons for eyes? Iconic

Comment: Agreed, this was a very easy one as story identification questions go, and I would have jumped in if Valorum hadn't beaten me to it.

Comment: @HarryWeasley They're easy if you already know the answer. The couple of story identification questions I've answered didn't require any research because I already knew what story they were referring to just from the few (unique) details they provided.

Comment: @HarryWeasley Just by the way, if Coraline has still stuck in your mind from back then, I cannot recommend enough that you should read some more Neil Gaiman.  It's pointless to give recommendations, because he has never written anything which wasn't world-class and utterly beautiful.

Comment: @Graham You never read Gaiman's biography of Duran Duran, did you?

Comment: @Graham , thanks, I'll try to find out other books by him!

Comment: @MagikarpMaster Close, [Valorum is a cyborg](http://www.darthsanddroids.net/episodes/0467.html).

Comment: @MikeScott: [The biography of Duran Duran](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062711/fullcredits?ref_=tt_ov_wr#writers) lists a lot of writers, but Gaiman doesn't seem to be among them. :-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin - ["Neil Gaiman: 'The book I wish I'd never written'"](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/hay-festival/11638724/Neil-Gaiman-The-book-I-wish-Id-never-written.html)

Comment: @JerryCoffin There must be more than one. This is the one I'm referring to: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Duran-Neil-Gaiman/dp/0862762596

Comment: @MikeScott: Apparently you didn't actually follow the link. What I linked is (I believe) the origin of the band's name, not anything about the band itself at all.

Comment: @MagikarpMaster That's what I wondered on chat some weeks ago!

Comment: @MagikarpMaster I'm putting my money on Valorum actually being a clone army.

Comment: Sometimes reputation gain is merely a matter of speed.

Comment: Just a comment about Coraline, I'm a grown man but I found the movie absolutely terrifying and didn't (couldn't!) watch it all the way through